# Warnings even when the WP_DEBUG set to false

Tags: cdn, warnings, wp-debug

The link https://vreqenz-stream.de/shop/ throws warning when opened on some devices and not on others. 
I thought it may be a cahce issue but I have cleared cache from WP-rocket and also browser. Just for the info I am using Plesk web admin tool.
Below is my WP_Config settings

```
ini_set('log_errors','On');
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

[image: Site snipshot with warning on top]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all of you for your response the issue got resolved. The problem was with cached copy of this link https://vreqenz-stream.de/shop/ . I had WP Rocket for caching and apparently it is not doing very good job of purging the cache. 
I got sure that it is cache issue when I defined the WP_CACHE as false which was true earlier and the warnings disappeared.

Comment: Thank you so much @veetrag. Mine was still showing, and WP_CACHE was at true. The second a updated WP_CACHE to false, warning vanished!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your php.ini file. display_errors may be turned on there and it might be overriding your wp_config file.

Comment: in php.ini I only have these two settings
zlib.output_compression = Off
memory_limit = 128M

Comment: Thanks for commenting the issue got resolved please check my comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two constants causing the error: `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` and  `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` , according to the error message I see.

Constants are just that -- '**constant**'. They can only be defined once. Once defined, you can't change them. (Cause if you changed them, they wouldn't be 'constant'.)

Check your `wp-config.php` file first for duplicate definitions of those. Then check your theme's files (functions.php first, other files next), and plugin files for 'extra' `DEFINES` of those constants.

**Added**

For instance:

```
DEFINE ($myconstant,"the value");
echo $myconstant;  // this is ok
$myconstant = 'new value'; // this will cause an 'already defined' error
```

One DEFINE for a constant. Use it any way you want, but don't change it.

Comment: Thanks for answering I will check that but the issue is even after setting the debug mode to false I am receiving these warnings. do you think that there is some cache issue or something else?

Comment: The errors are probably occuring anyway - by setting the debug values you get to see them on the screen, rather than having to look in the error.log file. The debug settings are not causing the errors, the setting is just allowing you to see them on the screen. The issue is that there are two DEFINE statements for the same constant variable. You can only have one DEFINE for a constant. Then you can't change the constant anywhere else. Look for a statement that is changing the constant to a new value. See my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks for commenting the issue got resolved please check my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins authors turn on error displaying due to inexperience.
Try searching for this exact string in wp-content folder.

```
'error_reporting('
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting the issue got resolved please check my comment.

Answer (score 0):

The `WP_DEBUG` setting only takes effect when `/wp-includes/default-constants.php` is loaded.

You are seeing these errors because they are occurring *before* that, ie. in `wp-config.php`... (which loads `wp-settings.php` which then consequently loads `/wp-includes/default-constants.php`)

If you want to use define constants multiple times without warnings you would need to check if they are already defined first:

```
if ( !defined( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT' ) ) {define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M' ); }
```

Of course only the first definition will be in effect, but this way you won't get the warnings and you can use this to allow for multiple fallback conditions.

But your solution is probably just to simply to check for and remove the multiple definitions, as it's doesn't sound like you are trying to do something more complex like this.

Comment: Thanks for commenting the issue got resolved please check my comment.